# SSRS dynamic column sizing

Tags: dynamic, size, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS 2008 report that contains a table with 3 columns.  The first columnn is variable in width and data.  i.e., the data could be 01-02 or 01-02-03-04-05-06-07-08.  The data can be anywhere from 5 characters in length to 105 characters....contiguous alphas.  No white space.  I don't want to wrap this column.  Is there any way to dynamically size a column or textbox based on the size of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matrix with few merged columns and hide columns depending on your text length.